# Create ExpiryDate during table definition in Oracle

Tags: oracle, ddl

I'm trying to create a table named MEMBER. The datatype for REGISTERDATE is DATE and the default value is SYSDATE. There is another column named EXPIRYDATE, datatype is DATE and the default value is 1 year after SYSDATE. So how am I going to create for the column of EXPIRYDATE when creating the table definition?
I tried REGISTERDATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
EXPIRYDATE DATE + 365,
It showed error..

Answer (score 0):

You're so close, you're just missing the `default` keyword and `sysdate` after `expirydate date`

```
-
create table MEMBER (
    REGISTERDATE date default sysdate,
    expirydate date default sysdate+365
)
```

test:

```
insert into MEMBER(REGISTERDATE) values (sysdate)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks... It able to create the table with no error but when I try to insert the values to the table, it showed me error.

Comment: Can you update your question and share the exact error ?

Comment: Sorry to ask... May I know on how to attach picture in the comment section?

Comment: @newbie The question needs to be in the question itself, rather than scattered across comments. Also, please don't send pictures of text.

Answer (score 0):

Not all years have 365 days; on average, only 3 out of 4. But you can literally define an expression that expresses "1 year after":

```
create table member (
    id number(*,0) not null primary key,
    registerdate date default sysdate,
    expirydate date default sysdate + interval '1' year
);
```

Remember that Oracle won't use the default value if you provide your own, even if it's `null`. You need to complete omit the field from the `INSERT INTO` statement.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bd59185137cb573993399c11df2b40f2)